# error logging in to windows azure sql database

Tags: windows, azure

Typed the correct username and password created in sql database, did the firewall settings and Silverlight ver is 5. Still unable to access. Need some help! There was an error connecting to the server. Failed to retrieve connection information. Try to login again.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the DS Server password from the portal. Navigate via Azure Management Console, then go to SQL Databases, then go to `SERVERS` tab. Then go to `DASHBOARD`. The find `Reset Administrator Password`, click that to reset the password.

Then try again.

Comment: Even when a new database is created with a new user and password, i still cant login. Also allowed the ip addresses already. Followed this guide http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sql-database/#PreReq2

Comment: Can you check whether you can telnet to 1433 to any server, I read somewhere that ISP may sometimes block 1433